# Incremental Neural Network Training

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, batch-processing, ram, training-data

I am working with a very large dataset with hundreds of long videos to be used as training and I'm using Google Colab to perform some tests. The whole code I wrote is quite simple and uses PyTorch.
When I try to perform the training, if I use more than 200 videos at a time, the RAM fullfills during the training and the Colab crashes. I noticed that this does not happens if I train with lower number of training videos.

For that reason I thought that my model may be trained incrementally creaing a structure as follows:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential( # create a model
    ...
    nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)

MAX_VIDEOS_PER_BATCH = 100
for current_batch in range (0, TOTAL_BATCHES): # Perform TOTAL_BATCHES trainings
    videos = []
    labels = []
    for index, video_file_name in enumerate(os.listdir(VIDEOS_DIR)): # Read 100 videos as training set
        if index < MAX_VIDEOS_PER_BATCH * current_batch:
           continue

        ... # read the video and add it to videos
        ... # add the considered labels to videos list


    video_training = torch.tensor(np.asarray(videos)).float() # (batch x frames x channels x height x width)
    learning_rate = 1e-4
    for t in range(ITERATIONS): # Train the model, if I already trained it the model is not resetted
        y_pred = model(torch.FloatTensor(np.asarray(video_training )))

        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, torch.tensor(labels))
        print("#" + str(t), " loss:" + str(loss.item()))

        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        with torch.no_grad():
        for param in model.parameters():
            param -= learning_rate * param.grad
```

My question is, is this method correct? I am training the network in a correct manner or this batches approach will create some damages or biases to the model?

When I go from batch 1 to batch 2, the model won't lose the previous trained knowledge, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct but the best way is to do the reverse.